# Is there a way to specific refer to only one id from this rest api using jsonpath?

Tags: home-automation

I'd like to just get data from UK.GOV when I send a GET request to this API.

https://api.covid19uk.live/

Can this be done using JSONpath? And how would this be done?

This is a bit of a prerequisite for my project because I am trying to make a sensor in Home Assistant that I can use to grab confirmed cases and deaths from Covid19 in the UK.

Home assistant has a built in REST platform structure:

https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/rest/

Which uses json_attributes and json_attributes_path. Therefore I must be able to do it this way in order for it to work in the desired way.

Comment: Yes, this can be done. I don't know what other kind of answer you expect.

Comment: My bad, ideally I'd like to know how it could be done, but I wasn't sure it was possible this way!

Comment: If you want to know *how* then you need to be *way* more specific about *what* data you want from that API.

Comment: Well I would like deaths and current cases in the UK from the UKGOV source within the API. There are two sources within the api itself, of which I'm only interested in UKGOV.